# if the same item in all four comboboxes are chosen

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

a newb practising more vb.net code.
I currently have four identical comboboxes named box1, box2, box3, box4.
in each of those comboboxes I have a list of words-

- dog
- cat
- bird
- fish

I've added these words through the 'properties'->'items'-->'collections' tab.

For now, I want to display a message- "you have 4 cats!" If the user selects the word 'cat' for all four comboboxes.

How would I write this code? I'm guessing I introduce a private function like 'onlycats' that sees if 'cat' is chosen for all 4 boxes... but I'm not to sure how to code based on what the user has chosen from the combobox.

Comment: does the user press a button or should the msg just pop up when it happens?

Comment: Yes so if the user presses a button saying e.g. "what animals do I have?" a msgbox should pop up saying "you have four cats!"

Comment: should it only say if the all 4 boxes are cats or could it also be: "you have 3 cats and 1 dog"

Comment: it should, but I want to focus on the "all animals are same" function first.

Comment: I posted a answer. Just put the values in a array and count them. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the selection of a ComboBox and present the results as a MsgBox after the User pressed a Button. You can do it like this:

```
    Dim Selection(4) As String
    Selection(0) = box1.Text
    Selection(1) = box2.Text
    Selection(2) = box3.Text
    Selection(3) = box4.Text
    MsgBox("You selected " & Selection.Where(Function(value) value = "dog").Count & " dogs!")
```

First of all I added everything to a Array and then search for a specific value and count it. You can count it like this:

`Selection.Where(Function(value) value = "value").Count`

The output is a Number. If "dog" is selected in all 4 boxes then the output is just `4` and you can write a Text around it. Hope it brings you on the right track.

============

If you just want to trigger something when 4 cats are selected then the count function also helps you. Just make a If Function

```
If Selection.Where(Function(value) value = "cat").Count = 4 Then
   MsgBox("you have 4 cats!")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested code but something like this:

```
sub CheckSame
  if box2.SelectedValue = box1.SelectedValue
      andalso box3.SelectedValue = box1.SelectedValue
      andalso box4.SelectedValue = box1.selectedValue then
    message.text = "You have 4 " & plural(box1.SelectedValue) & "!"
  else
    message.text = "You don't have 4 of the same animal"
  end if
end sub

function plural(s as String) as String
  select case s
    case "fish"
      return "fish"
    case else
      return s & "s"
  end select
end function
```